# Image bounding boxes from sprite sheet

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-segmentation

I've a sprite sheet containing a set of icons as shown here:

[image: image of symbols]

I'd like to get the `bounding box` (at pixel precision) of all icons inside it, some cases like list, grid have to be considered as only one icons. Any ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We can help you with your progamming issues. However, we're not going to do your work for you. Please show some effort: what research have you done? What have your tried already?

Comment: Dear  JHBonarius, far from me to ask people to do the job for me, and i've already googled it and came here as a last ressort (maye overestimated the kindness of stackoverflow).

Comment: Well, there are some assumptions you can make: - the bounding box is rectangular (square even?), - the bounding box has a minimum size, -(it seems) bounding boxes do not overlap. You could start by detecting all object parts and next determine which parts belong together.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue in your problem is that some icons contain disjoint parts. 
If all the icons were in only one part, you could just find the "connected components" (groups of white pixels) in your image and isolate them.

I don't know your level in image processing but to connect the parts of one icons, I would probably use dilation, which is a morphological method to expand (under constraints) the areas of maximum intensity in an image.

If you need any clarification, please let me know !

Comment: Good idea, but it will have trouble with the fact that the icons in the sprite map are not properly spaced apart from each other. The cross and the heart look like they are at least as close as the parts of the speaker icon.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I proposed dilation : you can choose a structural element such that dilation connects the parts of the same icon, but not icons together. I didn't check but it might be possible. The problem is we don't know if the algorithm should work for any configuration of these icons or for this configuration particularly.

Comment: Thank you all. @CsuGouv, i took some image processing courses when i was graduate (16 years) so my knowledge in this area is quite .. lost.

Comment: Not a problem at all, there are a lot of courses on it available online. If you want to implement this idea, you should search for Morphological Filtering which is a set of "basic" operations to be performed on bitmaps. To be honest, I can't ensure this will work for your problem, but that's how I would try to solve it

Comment: thanks a lot of help already, thanks for the tips, and your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not possible: only the humans have enough context to determine which of the disjoint parts belong together. You can approximate it using various ways, but it's a lost cause - and IMHO completely unnecessary. Imagine writing a test for this functionality - it's impossible, it requires a human in the loop, since the results for any particular icon sheet don't generalize. Knowing that the algorithm works for some sheet tells you nothing about whether it will work for some other sheet that you know nothing about a-priori.

It'd be simpler to manually colorize each sprite to have a color different than that of its neighbors. Then a greedy algorithm could find the bounding boxes easily without having to approximate anything.